# riak and map reduce - how to do a group using keys effiently

Tags: riak

I have a bucket that looks like this. They keys are part uuid as a random portion with date in YYYYMMDD and country appended.

How to a do an efficient query that will do the following:

```
select dt, country, camp, sum(count) as count from bucket where dt>'2012-10-03' and dt<'2012-10-05' group by dt,camp,country 

uiid201203US {'dt':'2012-10-03','camp':'a', 'country':'US', 'count':5}
uiid201204US {'dt':'2012-10-04','camp':'a', 'country':'US', 'count':5}
uiid201205US {'dt':'2012-10-05','camp':'a', 'country':'US', 'count':5}
uiid201203JP {'dt':'2012-10-03','camp':'a', 'country':'JP', 'count':5}
uiid201204JP {'dt':'2012-10-04','camp':'a', 'country':'JP', 'count':5}
uiid201205JP {'dt':'2012-10-05','camp':'a', 'country':'JP', 'count':5}
```